# What is the phase shift of a sinusoidal function?

Tags: trigonometry

Given the function f: $$ f(x) = \sqrt{3} \cos(2x) - \sin(2x) $$

Question: What is its amplitude and phase shift?

My attempt:

Let c be the hypothenuse of a triangle with the sides from the expression

$$ c = \sqrt{\sqrt{3}^2 + (-1)^2} = 2 $$

Then f can be written as

$$ f(x) = 2(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cos(2x) + \frac{-1}{2} \sin(2x)) $$

From trigonometric identities we know that

$$ \sin(α + β) = \sin(α)\cos(β) + \cos(α)\sin(β) $$

Comparing this expression to the one for f(x), one sees that

$$ \{ \sin(α) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}; \quad \cos(α) = \frac{-1}{2} \} \implies α = \frac{2\pi}{3} + 2 \pi n $$

Using this we rewrite f(x) as

$$ f(x) = 2 \sin(\frac{2\pi}{3} + 2x) $$

At this point it becomes unclear what the definition of phase shift is. According to many sources, it would be given by delta in

$$ f(x) = A \sin(k(\delta + x)) $$

So, in this case

$$ f(x) = 2 \sin(2(\frac{\pi}{3} + x)) $$

Clearly then

$$ \delta_{found} = \frac{\pi}{3} $$

However, the correct answer according to the book is

$$ \delta_{book} = \frac{2\pi}{3} $$

Which seems very strange!

Which is the proper definition, is the book really wrong on multiple occasions?

Comment: Depends; the found one is phase shift _after_ time compression; the book one is phase shift _before_ time compression.

Comment: There's a possible error when you go from the first to the second expression for $f(x)$. It looks like you have exchanged $\sin$ and $\cos$. Could that have to do anything with $\delta_{\text{found}} \neq \delta_{\text{book}}$?

Comment: you _time argument_ here is $2x$ not just $x$. At the very beginning you can set $t=2x$ and at the end you'd get $t+\frac{2\pi}{3}$, so there'd be no hesitations. :)

Comment: That is an interesting point of view, @Caran-d'Ache. I understand phase shift as the shift from $ sin(2x) $, and in a graph it is plain that the actual phase shift $ \frac{\pi}{3} $!

Comment: I don't know where you got this definition from but the classical [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_%28waves%29).

Comment: Yep, phase shift is $\delta$ from $\sin(kx + \delta)$.

Comment: So, varying the x coefficient will change the phase shift? Plot $ y_1 = \sin(kx + \delta) $ and $ y_2 = \sin(kx) $ for some constant $ \delta $ and vary k, notice that the distance between the two waves will vary with k!